# zsh invocation -s flag

Tags: zsh

In documentation (man zsh, Invocation section) we find that `zsh -s` forces the shell to read commands from the standard input. If the `-s` flag is not present and an argument is given, the first argument is taken to be the pathname of a script to execute."

Can you give an example, please, how to force the first argument to be a pathname of script to execute?

Answer (score 2):

The "forcing" refers to the flag causing the shell to read commands from standard input. You don't have to do anything special to make the shell execute a script: `zsh script`.

Actually, it's not simply the first argument that is used as the script location. The `zshall` manpage "Invocation" section contains the following example: `zsh -x -o shwordsplit scr`. Here `scr` is the script to be executed while the rest of the arguments are other options.

Comment: Yes, it's not simply to set the first argument as the script location. So that question is about.

Comment: So in `zsh -x -o shwordsplit scr` no flag `-s` is given but the first argument is treated as script name, not script path.

Comment: Yes, the documentation also states that "If there are any remaining arguments after option processing, and neither of the options -c or -s was supplied, the first argument is taken as the file name of a script containing shell commands to be executed." If you want to be sure that option processing is finished before you provide the script path, use -b or -- (end of invocation section).